# Kendo style issue - UI elements out of place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendonumerictextbox

I have a Kendo DropDownList on an Angular MVC project.  Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.111 m) and IE10 renders it as 2 elements side-by-side. This issue remains with all Kendo elements with 2 HTML elements, such as NumericTextBoxs. Is this a bug? Is there a fix for it?

[image: Kendo DropDownList out of place element]
[image: Kendo NumericTextBox out of place element]

This is how the HTML looks:

[image]

This is how I declare the drop down list

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Name: </h4>
        <select kendo-drop-down-list style="width: 200px">
            <option>Name 1</option>
            <option>Name 2</option>
            <option>Name 3</option>
            <option>Name 4</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Kendo style sheets is conflicted with other used styles in your project. Track css rules effects.

Comment: Are there any tools that lets you easily track this?

Comment: Just inspect element by browser and see affected css rules to your elements :)

Comment: Thanks.  You were right! It was a custom css rule that was overriding the default kendo style

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect element by browser and see affected css rules to your page elements. You may wanna change some of them to work with each other.